# TWILIO-API: List recording within a data range

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

this example provided on Twilio website is not working:

```
$records = $client->recordings->read(0, 10, array(
"datecreatedBefore" => "2016-12-04",
"datecreatedAfter" => "2016-12-01"    
));
```

It still shows also recordings outside this range. Any idea how to filter by date?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Twilio PHP SDK version are you using?

Comment: The latest one downloaded from Twilio GitHub: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/
What i noticed is that for recording there is this object "dateCreated" (that is a Date Object).

I can search for data range for Call Logs, issue for me i sonly with recordings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like there maybe a mistake in translating from the [v4 Twilio PHP library to the v5 library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php). Previously, the `getIterator` method took a page and page size argument before the remaining options for filtering.

```
$recordings = $client->account->recordings->getIterator(0, 50, array(
    "DateCreated<" => "2016-10-15",
    "DateCreated>" => "2016-10-12"
))
```

With the v5 library, [`read` takes the array of options first, followed by a limit and then page size](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-php/class-Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.RecordingList.html#_read). So, to use the iterator with a limit of 10 you need to call it like this:

```
$recordings = $client->recordings->read(array(
    "datecreatedBefore" => "2016-12-04",
    "datecreatedAfter" => "2016-12-01" 
), 10, 10);
```

Let me know if this helps at all.